# Unable to create flamegraph for nodeJS process

Tags: javascript, node.js, perf, flamegraph

I am trying to profile a nodeJS REST API using perf utility. command I'm using is `perf record -F 99 -p 5395 -g -- sleep 60` 5395 being process id. 
It works properly and writes data to perf.data file.

`[ perf record: Woken up 6 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 1.360 MB perf.data (~59425 samples) ]`

However when I'm trying to create report from it using `perf script > out.perf` I'm getting error `Failed to open /tmp/perf-5395.map, continuing without symbols`. Which basically means perf could not decompile code to show javascript code in output file. How to get this map file? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Missing --perf_basic_prof_only_functions on node.

E.g. `node --perf_basic_prof_only_functions app.js`

Comment: I am new to linux.
Can you please elabourate `perf record --perf_basic_prof_only_functions -F 99 -p 26882 -g -- sleep 60` tells me `unknown option `perf_basic_prof_only_functions'`

Comment: Add that to your node process like this `node --perf_basic_prof_only_functions app.js` , then use `perf` as before.